# I want to get the ISBN form table but unable to get text content

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```js
document.querySelector("#book-list").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let a = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.previousSibling;
  console.log(a.textContent);
})

document.getElementById("book-list");
const row = document.createElement("tr");
row.innerHTML = `
<td>${book.title}</td>
<td>${book.author}</td>
<td>${book.ISBN}</td>
<td><a href="#" class="delete-btn delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-minus delete" ></i></a></td>
`;
```

I want to get the ISBN from the HTML table data but I am not getting. I have tried textcontent and innerText but none of them worked.

Comment: Are you getting anything? Is there an error in your console?

Comment: Why do you have JavaScript in the HTML box of the snippet?

Comment: It's really difficult to debug this without seeing the actual HTML. And what is meant by `document.getElementById("book-list")`? Is this already in your HTML? You "retrieve" the element, but don't save it to a variable.

Comment: @mykaf no when I output let a = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.previousSibling;
  console.log(a)                                                                                                                                                 I am getting #text object in console

Comment: `e.target.parentElement.parentElement` depends on which element you click on. If you click on a TD, this will be the table. If you click on the `<i>` it will be the `<tr>`

Comment: @mykaf document.getElementById("book-list") this is working fine , Its in my HTML code.

Comment: I think you want `previousElementSibling`

Comment: @Barmar I am getting tr and wants ISBN when clicking on <i>

Comment: @Barmar by doing previousElementSibling  i got #text object. But I want ISBN

Comment: @Barmar  I am getting text node but when applying textContent or nodeValue I am getting empty(nothing).

Comment: @mykaf I am getting text node but when applying textContent or nodeValue I am getting empty(nothing).

Comment: What does your rendered html look like?

Comment: @mykaf Its showing the books list. this code is for deleting a book by its ISBN value. By above code I am getting #text node but not getting the value of the text node.

Comment: You're getting the text node between the elements, not the contents of the element.

Comment: If you have the `tr` in a variable, you can use `tr.cells[2].innerText` to get the ISBN.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah! cells[2].innerText worked. Thanks for helping me out. But why textContent and nodeValue and also nodeType were showing empty

Comment: Because you're not getting to the correct element.

Comment: I recommend you use classes rather than hard-coding positions like this. `e.target.closest("tr").querySelector(".isbn").textContent`

Comment: @Barmar Okay understood. Thanks so much for helping and spending your time and efforts. have a nice day.